# jquery Storing the value of an input box, then recalling it elsewhere

Tags: jquery, forms

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    var english = $("input #rawr").val()
    $("h1 em").append(" " + english + " "); //Current submit brings up 'undefined'
    return false;

});

<form>
    <input type="text" name="rawr" id="rawr" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [ancestor descendant](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant) selector, which isn't what you want.

The selector is looking for an element with an `id = rawr`, child of an INPUT element .

Remove the space on your selector:

```
var english = $("input#rawr").val();
```

or don't use the tag name at all, since you have a unique ID:

```
var english = $("#rawr").val();
```

Also don't forget your semicolons!

Answer (score 0):

Make the english var:

```
var english = $("#rawr").val()
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked, but why does the input selector mess up the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var english = $("#rawr", $(this)).val();
    $("h1 em").append(" " + english + " ");
});

<form>
    <input type="text" name="rawr" id="rawr" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```